# Math Algorithms

Tags: performance, algorithm, math, optimization, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to understand the concept of Algorithms and basically how they improve performance of a computer program.

So assume, I have to write a program which generates a list of numbers by,

1. Starts with the number 1.
2. Adds 3 to it.
3. Stores the result (1+3=4) in the list.
4. Adds 5 to the new number.
5. Stores the result (4+5=9) in the list.
6. Keeps alternatively adding 3 and 5 to the latest number in the list.

Now this is a very simple program and lets say it the program has to stop when the number is greater than 10,00,000, and lets suppose a simple program to do this takes 10 seconds to generate the list.

How does one design an algorithm for this problem such that the program takes lesser time to generate the list.

**NOTE**- I am trying to understand the concept here with an example, the above times mentioned are random and not factual. It would be great if someone could help me understand the concept with a 'simple' example, if they do not wish to use the above example.

Comment: You should ask your question here : [Math](http://math.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Not really, this is just for an explanation on algorithms and how to enhance performance of an algorithm.  And if I'm looking at it right, this should be a O(n) algorithm, since you have to run through all n(in this case 10000000) elements once.

Comment: I think you need to describe the problem a bit more clearly. "Generating" a list like that can be done O(1) since the list itself is constant.
@Siamak.A.M: I don't think this question qualifies. The Math site is for math students and professionals.

Comment: This question's tricky, as it's essentially, "how do programmers think up their optimizations?". It's roughly equivalent to asking a writer, "where do you get your ideas?" You might get some interesting responses, but you won't get a step-by-step algorithm that generates ideas/optimizations.

Comment: Firstly, I hope this is the right place to post. As I am not worried about the math part, but rather the designing and implementation part. Thanks Siamak, CBredlow, Come From and Kevin. Kevin you sort of nailed what I wanted to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you've given above (the list of steps to produce your list) *is* an algorithm.

Significant improvements in efficiency typically mean changing from one algorithm to another that accomplishes the same end with less work. For example, for the algorithm above, you might try to avoid creating the list (as such) at all, and instead substitute an algorithm that can quickly generate the result for any particular spot in the list -- given N as input, it would do something like

```
int n = N/2; 
int m = N-n; 
return 1 + n * 3 + m * 5;
```

Note that this code probably isn't exactly correct (I don't think it handles odd versus even input numbers quite correctly), but you get the general idea -- instead of carrying out an entire series of operations to get one result, it carries out a much smaller number of operations to produce the equivalent result.

Comment: +1, exactly what I was gonna say ([exact solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%28n%29+%3D+a%28n-2%29+%2B+8%2C+a%281%29+%3D1%2C+a%282%29+%3D+4)). Also, this combines well with indexers/iterators and memoization (depending on language).

Comment: +1 for pointing out that an algorithm is already there. However I think babsdoc fails to describe the actual problem. Algorithms are pretty much meaningless without a properly defined problem.

Comment: Thanks Jerry. You made me understand that I dont necessarily need an algorithm to generate the list, but I would be in a better position to have an algorithm if I was to generate only a part/spot in the list. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the example you gave you can't be much faster. You have to output the whole list and the algorithm you described does it efficiently.

Lets modify the problem a bit: you just output the first number grater than 1000000. This can be solved smarter than generating the whole list.

Comment: Thanks Henry, you said the same thing as Jerry in a simple manner.

Answer (score 1):

When one looks toward improving a program or snippet of code's performance (i.e. using a better algorithm to compute the same result), it is important to consider the visible output of the algorithm.  That is to say how does the (output of the) algorithm get used or consumed?  In other words, what does the algorithm return, and how is that return consumed?

The above steps in your question indicate that a list should be built, but then what?  Were one to merely discard the results (you could easily write such a program or function), a good optimizer (human or machine) could substitute a null or empty program or function based on the fact that the result is never used.  (Seriously: this is a common problem in benchmarks, an algorithm computes some result to measure performance of generated code but that result isn't used so the compiler removes potentially whole loops, memory allocations, maybe whole functions!)

So, what really matters regarding the setup of your question about the analysis of how to go about changing an algorithm for better performance is: to identify or specify the portion of the output that gets used (by some other part of the program).

Given a specification (of how the algorithm's results are consumed) we can work backward to find algorithmic improvements that yield the same results with less work.

When we compose algorithms, we can work thru the compositions to identify opportunities for improvement.  Put another way, the algorithm you describe above might be used by some other algorithm to find only one value at a time, which means that Jeffry's solution is the appropriate better performing replacement algorithm.

However, a different consumer of your list algorithm may request a different part of its visible effect, and so a different optimization or algorithmic substitution might be appropriate.  Such is the case as I describe above if the results are not used at all, and yet still, another consumer might just want to count the number of nodes in the list, in which case a wholly different optimization is more appropriate.

In some cases, we can specify that the algorithm returns something, and we are forced to generate code for one reason or another without knowing who is consuming the result.  In those cases, an optimizer (human or machine) would be forced to make a pessimistic presumption that every visible effect that is returned is potentially consumed.  For example, let's assume that the list is was what is returned (as additional specification in your the question), and we prevent any optimizer from seeing further into the consumption, we'd in all likelihood have to actually build the list (and so Jeffry's answer wouldn't work).

In short, we cannot fully analyze the problem and its solution space without additional context.

In part, that additional context takes the form of an explicit return statement (or some other externally visible side effect, such as modifying a global variable).

And further, some of that additional context may take the form of another algorithm that is enclosing, invoking or composing (with the original algorithm of interest); hence, the process of optimizing is recursive, and yields better results the more the (human or machine) can "see".

Comment: Thanks Erik. I would like to think that I understand completely what you have mentioned, but given my limited understanding, I do get some of it. I'll keep revisiting this question whenever I am lost and see if I find and understand more of the stuff that all you folks have been so kind to share. Regards -

Answer (score 0):

Let's start off saying that you don't *use* an algorithm for improving the performance of a computer program; the algorithm **is** the program (by definition, an algorithm is a finite sequence of operations that solve a problem).

There are of course famous algorithms, already invented by wise men, that can be perfectly applied to a problem (your problem regards graphs? Dijkstra's algorithm for the shortest path, Ford-Fulkerson for the max flow, Prim and Kruskal for a Minimum Spanning Tree, and so on). You generally would want to re-use such well-performing algorithms into your program, instead of re-writing them from scratch.

You would want to use them because

1. Re-writing it probably will take you to have a worse performance
2. Re-writing it will definitely consume your time, that you could spend solving the problem (assuming that the use of the algorithm is for a subset of your problem, i.e. "for solving my problem I need first to reorder an array" - the reordering of the array is a necessary step for the solution, but not your problem)

As for number 1 also there are some math calculation involved, since to measure the performance of an algorithm you have to do some things that are better explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Hope I was clear in solving your doubts, unfortunately I don't like big-o notations and such performance calculations so I can't be more helpful than just pointing to the wikipedia link

Comment: Why wouldn't one use an algorithm for improving the performance of a computer program ?  What do you think optimising compilers use ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get the second question - as for the first one, I didn't say that you don't use an algorithm for improving performances, I said you'd use a library function that implements that algorithm instead of writing your own

Comment: Grasshopper glanced through the wikipedia link. Might revisit it in detail later. Thanks.